# Use insert_one is not woring when data include datetime.datetime

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I use `Python scrapy`(1.8.0) to scrapy some data and save it to `mongodb` with `pymongo`.

It works when I use `Python2` and older `pymongo` version.

But when I try to use `Python3` and `pymongo 3.10.1`, I found insert document doesn't work.

I found the issue comes from `datetime`,

Like this:

```
'releasedTime': [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 17, 14, 30),datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 16, 18, 10),datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 17, 22, 0)]
```

The date data comes from like this:

```
stripSingleTime = singleTime.strip() # 14:30
myTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(stripSingleTime, '%H:%M').time() # 14:30:00
myDateTime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), myTime) # 2020-01-17 14:30:00
# x is my for loop argument
myDateTimeArray[x].append(myDateTime)  # [[datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 17, 14, 30)], []]
```

Here is about `insert_one`:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()
import datetime

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    global theaters
    theaters = []

    def __init__(self):
        connection = MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        self.db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = self.db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        print ('Pipelines => open_spider =>', spider)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        global theaters

        self.collection = self.db[type(item).__name__.replace('_Item','')]

        if  item['theater'] not in theaters:
            theaters.append(item['theater'])
            self.collection.remove({'theater': item['theater']})

        # self.collection.insert_one(mydict) is working
        mydict = { 'name': 'RUNOOB', 'alexa': '10001', 'url': 'https://www.runoob.com' }

        test = {
        'geometry': {'coordinates': [120.196866, 22.99322], 'type': 'Point'}, 
        'phone': '06-2205151',
        'theater': 'TodayTainan',
        'movie': [{
        'enName': 'The Lion King',
        'goodMinePoint': 0.75,
        'imdbScore': '8.5',
        'photoHref': 'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/June2019/M07RYsvcBWpi3xJtjCQF-2714x3878.jpg',
        'releasedTime': [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 17, 14, 30)],
        'rottenScore': '93%',
        'videoId': ['MQuUkET0lQg', 'he2rj_8XwsE']
        }]
        }

        self.collection.insert_one(test) # insert the dummy object test is not working

        self.collection.create_index([("geometry", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])

        return item
```

Why `self.collection.insert_one(test)` is not working ?

I guess something wrong between `pymongo` and `mongodb`. They don't deal with my `datetime`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Define "is not working". Does it error? The document is not inserted but no errors? The document inserted with unexpected data?

Comment: If I set the print('test') after `self.collection.insert_one(test)`. It won't be printed. And If I set try except with  `self.collection.insert_one(test)`, the code will run to catch, but print(err) is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    self.collection.insert_one(test) # insert the dummy object test is not working
```

to

```
    import traceback
    try:
        result = self.collection.insert_one(test) # insert the dummy object test is not working
        print (result.inserted_id)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

and report back the output.

Comment: Thanks Belly !  I try your code and see the output shows `KeyError: 'AntispamItem does not support field: _id'` and I found the solution. Thanks.